# Using Gradle project-report and jacoco plugins together

Tags: gradle

I'd like to use both the Gradle [project-report](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/project_reports_plugin.html) and [jacoco](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) plugins in my project.  To illustrate the problem I'm having though, I opened build.gradle at: gradle-1.7-rc-1/samples/testing/jacoco/quickstart and modified it to be:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "project-report"
```

running a gradle projectReport then gives me the error:

```
gradle projR
:dependencyReport
:propertyReport
:taskReport FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':taskReport'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':jacocoTestReport'.
```

Any advice on how to get these two plugins to play nice together would be appreciated (note, they both work independently of each other).

Thanks

Comment: Nope.  Still failing in gradle 1.9-rc4

Comment: Fixed in version 1.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covered by [GRADLE-2917](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2917), will be fixed in version 1.10 as described in the [Gradle Forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/jacoco_and_project_report_plugin_incompatibility)